# QTableWidget Scrolling With Selected Item

Tags: qt, qt5.5

So i am using a QTableWidget as a logger of sorts for a user, with new rows being inserted at the top, and bottom ones falling off eventually as i read in updates every second or so.

I am currently running these 3 commands to keep the user from being able to do anything with the widget.

```
summaryTable->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
summaryTable->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
summaryTable->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

This works, the user cant select a box(doesnt get highlighted more on that later), cant edit a box, all is good.

Except even if a user clicks on a cell, even though its not highlighted visibly there is still something allowing it to be selected such that when that cell gets "pushed" down below the current scroll area from inserts at the top the table begins scrolling down to follow this cell all the way to the bottom.

Obviously this is confusing, if a user clicks a cell within a few seconds its going to keep scrolling them down the table over and over again and it becomes a fight for them to scroll back up and click on a header or something to prevent future scrolling.

How do i prevent this?  I thought by preventing selection and turning off what i did it would  stop this, but there is still some type of selection happening within QT even if its not visible as its tracking the selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, didnt realize there is a SetAutoScroll method, setting this to false fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This Method May Work QTableWidget::scrollToItem() or 
QTableWidget::scrollTo() is will Work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually scroll the item by putting row index as -

```
self.ui.tableWidget.verticalScrollBar().setValue(index)
```

OR

You can auto scroll the item by current index:

```
row = self.ui.tableWidget.currentIndex().row()
self.ui.tableWidget.verticalScrollBar().setValue(row)
```